# Delete a boundary line in ArcMap while exporting a map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

When I create a map layout with a background map there is no boundary line (photo 1). But when I open the jpeg file the boundary appears (photo 2). How can I delete it?

Photo 1
[image]

Photo 2
[image]

Photo 3
[image]

Photo 4

[image]

It appears on a certain scale and disappears when I zoom in/out. But always present when I export map.

Comment: Is the line still there if you export a map without the background image?  If so try turning off different vector layers, especially the one with the yellow labels, to see if one of them is the problem.  If it is see if the labels on or off are the issue.  You might try repairing its geometry as well.

Comment: Yes, even when i close the background image. I turned oof all layers and background map and this is what i got (Photo 3). This line stretches for very long distance. I dont even know what does it represents and how it came here

Comment: These are not labels, btw, i draw them using drawing tool.

Comment: Since you are drawing shapes you might see if you accidentally drew a line in.  I don't have ArcMap here but somewhere in View - Data Frame Properties you can uncheck a box so no shapes or annotation is displayed.  But at the scale of your added picture you might see if you can use the pointer to select the line and if so delete it.  I suppose it could be in either the view or layout so you would try both.

Comment: I think i found the answer - i  changed the coordinate system from GCS to PCS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the coordinate system of a data frame. I changed it from GCS to PCS and the boundaries disappeared.